# Adding values to serialised Array Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to add data to a preserialised array. Its not working. Anyone spot why?

```
$("#show-friends").live("click", function() {
    var friendSelector = $("#jfmfs-container").data('jfmfs');   
    var sendArr = $(friendSelector).serializeArray();


    sendArr.push({ name: "userid", value: "<?php echo $userId;?>" });
    sendArr.push({ name: "fid", value: "<?php echo $fid;?>" });
    $.post({
         url:'test.php', 
         data: sendArr, 
         });
});
```

Edit: I changed my code to:

```
 $("#show-friends").live("click", function() {
    var friendSelector = $("#jfmfs-container").data('jfmfs');  
    var sendArr = friendSelector.serializeArray();
        $.post({
             url:'test.php',
             data: "name=<?php echo $userId;?>&fid=<?php echo $fid;?>&jsondata="+sendArr,
             });
});
```

However I get a error friendSelector.serializeArray is not a function

Comment: If the problem is supposed to be those 'push' method calls, I don't see anything wrong with them.  What gets posted?

Comment: I dont know I dont see anything being posted. *edit: nevermind it returns as a null value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [`$post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) call is incorrect.  You don't pass an object like you would for [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  You pass the url, then the data (if any), and then a callback (if you want).

It should be:

```
$.post('test.php', sendArr);
```

Or with `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'test.php', 
    data: sendArr,
    type: 'POST'
});
```

**EDIT**: When you do `$("#jfmfs-container").data('jfmfs')`, this is return you the value of the `jfmfs` data.  `friendSelector.serializeArray` doesn't work, because `friendSelector` is whatever the data was, not a jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks! It worked with no issues but i cant see whats being posted

Comment: @Rory: Where can you not see what's being posted?  How are you accessing it?

Comment: I tried to do the traditional var_dump php method. I changed up my code to. See above

Comment: @Rory: Check my edit, there is something else I noticed about your code.